# MvcSiteMapProvider dynamic xml Sitemap Generation with MVC Attrivbute Routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am working on a MVC5 project where I need to create a sitemap.

I have created my routes using Route Attribute on the controller actions.

I am using a Dynamic node provider as specified in the documentation for MvcSiteMapProvider and it works fine for one of my controllers, however for another one it is displaying the query string paramaters for each mapped route so for example

I am getting

www.url.com?SelectedCulture=en-gb

when I am expecting

www.url.com/en-gb

My routes all work fine and if I use my application it is working fine aswell... It just doesnt create a sitemap which i am expecting

The Dynamic provider that I created is populating the required attribute that matches the route.

Anyone have any ideas?